# Measurability of function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g: C[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a Borel-measurable function.
Define $f: C[0,\infty) \times C_0[0,\infty) \to C[0,\infty)$ by $f(y,z)(t)=y(t)+z(1-g(y))\mathbf{1}_{\{t > g(y)\}}$.

In a proof we are studying it is then claimed that $f$ is measurable as the composition of measurable functions. However we don't see this.
We tried proving that $\sigma: [0,\infty) \times C_0[0,\infty) \to R^{[0,\infty)}$ defined by $\sigma(x,y)(t) =y(t-x)\mathbf{1}_{\{t > x\}}$ is measurable by considering inverse images, but this didn't really work out.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks complicated... What if you try decomposing your function in several simpler function like $$A(y, z) = y(t) + z(t);$$
$$B(y, z) = (y, z\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{t > g(y)\}});$$
$$C(y, z) = (y, z(1-g(y))).$$

Maybe I made a mistake in decomposition, but you get the idea.

Now, if you look at $(A\circ B\circ C)(y, z)(t)$, you seem to get your function. You just have to prove that $A, B$ and $C$ are measurable :)

You definetely should use the fact that continuous functions are Borel-measurable, but I have no idea where you could use the fact that $z$ vanishes at the infinity...